# in kendo Grid row and column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I'd like to get the desired row and column's values from the kendo Ui grid.

When I click the A column, I would like get the index value for Low and col in column A. also wants to fetch the same Low B column.

For example

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
$(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
    var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
    //alert(rowIdx + '-' + colIdx);

    //How do I get a value from B column?

});
```

Comment: Please post additional info such as the target columns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve values from the row clicked, you can get the `dataItem` from the clicked grid row by using:

```
grid.tbody.on("click", "tr", function (e) {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);    
});
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/aFUcE/2) to demonstrate the above.